# Structured streaming doesnt get individual file name with input_file_name()

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a structured streaming job that reads in a bunch of json.gz files under the following directory and writes to a delta table

```
headFolder
|- 00
|-- file1.json.gz
|- 01
|-- file2.json.gz
...
|- 23
|-- file24.json.gz
```

The structured streaming I'm running is as follows

```
spark.readStream
.format('cloudFiles')
.options({"cloudFiles.format": "json", "cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode": "rescue"})
.schema(schema_predefined)
.load("./headFolder/")
.withColumn("input_file_path", input_file_name())
.writeStream
.format("delta")
.outputMode("append")
.options({'checkpointLocation': checkpoint_path, 'path': output_path})
.trigger({'once': True})
.queryName("query_name")
.start()
```

I omitted some details in the query above, please take all undeclared parameters as pre-defined. After I run the job, all the 24 files were processed and I can validate that data was correct. However, the input_file_name() function didn't work as I was expecting.

When I check the `input_file_name` column, I was expecting 24 distinct records since their key names are different. However, I see only around 5 filenames, which varies based on file size. After I looked into the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html), indeed it returns the file name of the TASK instead of the individual files, thus since I'm reading from the top level, Spark automatically divides the 24 hours into several tasks and picked one name from the files read.

My question is, is there still a way to accurately record the filename for the file processed under the current framework? I don't want to change the file path or force it to run one task per file for runtime reasons.

Thank you!

Comment: it worked for us, we are using `input_file_name` function to get the file names. what do you mean only 5 files? are these 5 files are the files available in the path you are trying to read?

Comment: yeah. I think it divided the whole folder into 5 tasks and just took one random file name from each task

Comment: could you try specifying this while reading and check, if its working fine `.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 10)`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I just bumped into this problem myself.